# Paypal Rest API activate billing plan

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I am trying to activate a billing plan that is previously created and I get the malformed json error.

Activate endpoint:

```
"/v1/payments/billing-plans/{plan-id}"
```

Request body:

```
[

   {

      "path": "",

      "value": {

         "state": "ACTIVE"

      },

      "op": "replace"

   }

]
```

In PHP:

```
$payLoad = json_encode(array(array(
    'path' => "",
    'value' => array(
        'state' => 'ACTIVE'
    ),
    'op' => 'replace'

)));
```

And the response I get:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"....}
```

Edit: I have also tried path to have a value of "/"

```
"path": "\/",
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Can you try this request body :[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/",
        "value": {
            "state": "ACTIVE"
        }
    }
]

Comment: Actually this is what I am trying, I changed to try with empty value but still the same error. Should mention that php evaluates it to "\/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this answer is a little late but I had the same issue recently and thought I'd share the solution for anyone else who may run into it.

If you plan on using the PHP SDK for recurring payment (plan) PATCH calls the source needs altering slightly.

It's caused by line 56 in PPHttpConnection.php, the switch statement only attaches post fields if the method is POST. However, PATCH requests also send a payload and therefore also require post fields to be added, without them the API returns a malformed JSON error as it's not receiving any content.

```
switch($this->httpConfig->getMethod()) {
        case 'POST':
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;                     
}
```

Change the above to:

```
 switch($this->httpConfig->getMethod()) {
        case 'POST':
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break; 
        case 'PATCH':
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;           
}
```

The PATCH call should then work perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is what I actually did, but I thought it wasn't in the questions context to post it, anyway marking this as best answer.

Comment: Thanks, makes more sense from the context of the Paypal SDK I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kind of late but this worked on postman with PATCH request (instead of POST)

```
[
    {
        "path": "/",
        "value": {
            "state": "ACTIVE"
        },
       "op": "replace"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanx. In my case error was just typo. Make sure you're sending array of operations (json array) instead of one operaion object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code , it works for me :

```
<?php
    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
    $header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-34L0290663823456FEE7TINY';
    $data ='[
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/",
            "value": {
                "state": "ACTIVE"
            }
        }
    ]';

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set connection properties
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $err = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch) ;
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if( $err )
    {
    echo 'error';
    }
    if( $errmsg ){
    echo '<h3>Error</h3>'.$errmsg;
    }
    else
    echo $result;


    ?>
```

Comment: The problem was elsewhere(not in the given code), but I will leave the question and answer so it can be useful for someone in the future. The code in this answer works.